# HTTP protocol POST stream request and responds; THEORY

Tags: sockets, http, methods, stream

I was wondering how one would go on about setting up a HTTP data stream. The HTTP is not used for webdesign only for retriving information and making information availible online. This information or data will be used by embedded systems so there no need for HTML or such.

I came across the GET and POST methods, but they seem to be on the client side, as a request method. I guess a continue'e stream could be POSTed, but how would a server provide a HTTP stream to a client, would this also be done by the POST method?

(REAL Time UDP stream will most likely be implemented)

Comment: What do you think streaming means? How do you think HTTP works? Why are you mentioning UDP? Your question doesnt'really make sense as-is. Can you explain a bit more what exactly you are trying to do and how HTTP and UDP fit in there?

Comment: i am mentioning UDP because the information is REAL time so fast delivery and only the recent information is relevant, no need to request back older packets like TCP would.

Comment: I know HTTP works by URLS and client requests to acces some kind of HTTP files probally. these files would contain the stream information perhaps, the client could get paired with an server IP address for the steam he wants to read out, and keep refreshing the file. But more elegant would be if there was a stream function in http, perhaps its the task of the server to keep the file filled with the stream content

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering how one would go on about setting up a HTTP data stream.

Me too. HTTP isn't a 'data stream'. It is a request/response protocol.

> The HTTP is not used for webdesign

I agree. HTML is used for that, and CSS, and various other things. HTTP is a network protocol, not a presentation layer.

> only for retri[e]ving information and making information availible online.

That is correct. It didn't really need re-stating after more than 20 years.

> This information or data will be used by embedded systems so there no need for HTML or such.

Fine.

> I came across the GET and POST methods, but they seem to be on the client side, as a request method.

Correct.

> I guess a continue'e stream could be POSTed,

It's anybody's guess, depending entirely on what you mean by "a continue'e stream". What is that?

> but how would a server provide a HTTP stream to a client, would this also be done by the POST method?

No.

> (REAL Time UDP stream will most likely be implemented)

There is no such thing as 'real time UDP' short of RTP and friends, or 'UDP stream' either, let alone 'real time UDP stream', and HTTP is not defined over non-streaming protocols.

Your question remains obscure. I've done my best with it.